# xcode install cocoa project at launchpad

Tags: xcode, cocoa, installation, launchpad

When I run my Mac OS X Cocoa project, Xcode says build succeeded and the application opens, but never appears as installed. When I go to launchpad I can't find the application. Seems it is only emulated. I need to watch how is shown in the launchpad with the icon and the title. How can I install the application from the xcode?

I have xcode 6.1.

Need help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apps inside of `/Applications` and `~/Applications` are displayed in Launchpad. When you launch from Xcode the apps are copied to a temporary build directory. So you have to copy your app to the correct location.

If you only want the Debug version, because you want to test your app, you can simply locate the app bundle in Finder:

Open the `Products` group in Xcode, right click the .app file and select "Show in Finder". In Finder simply drag & drop the app into the `Applications` folder.

[image: Screenshot Xcode sidebar]

---

If you need the Release version you can archive the app. Select Product/Archive in the Xcode menu.

[image: Xcode Menu]

In the Organizer you choose Export, in the Export wizard you select "Export as Mac Application". You can directly save it into the Applications directory, or save it somewhere else and copy or move it into the Applications directory

[image: Xcode Organizer]